# Video via OMXControl don t have sound, omxplayer play it fine

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, raspbian, youtube-dl

I m trying to use the [Lamba Labs Beirut Hackerspace 's RPiTv](http://blog.donaldderek.com/2013/06/build-your-own-google-tv-using-raspberrypi-nodejs-and-socket-io/#comment-627)
I have configured my Raspberry Pi for it (Raspibian, node.js, omxplayer, youtube-dl...)
If I download a video and play it in omxplayer, all work fine.
When I try to do it via the node.js app, the video play fine, but there is no audio
The screen is a HP ProDisplay P201 linked by a DVI cable
Audio by a audio casque linked with jack

I can modify the code, but since I m still learning javascript, I d like to avoid it for now.

I m thinking that the lack of audio can come from:

-Is there limitation between omxcontrol and omxplayer? (Is the volume just set to 0 when omxplayer is called, or is there is no audio at all?)

_-In that case, what is the volume control option for omxcontrol, tried google but it seem he don t like me today

-Is it something I made wrong when installing omxcontrol or node.js? (I assume youtube-dl and omxplayer are fine, since it play well when lauched manually)

I know I ask a lot, but even a hint will help.

Comment: I figured it out, I just wasn t watching the right code. I was thinking the problem came from remote.js, but then I saw omxcontrol was starting omxplayer with -o hdmi flag, since the screen didn t had audio output, the audio was lost. I removed the flag and all work fine.

Hope it can help somebody else.

Regards

DrakaSAN

Comment: You should write that as an answer and accept it ;)

Comment: I couldn t write it as answer when I found it, too new to stack overflow for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I just wasn t watching the right code.
I was thinking the problem came from remote.js, but then I saw omxcontrol was starting omxplayer with -o hdmi flag (in omxcontrol/index.js), since the screen didn t had audio output, the audio was lost.
I removed the flag and all work fine.

Hope it can help somebody else.